# Iomanip setprecision() Method Isn't Working as It Should Only on the First Line, Why?

Tags: c++, time, clock, execution, iomanip

So I'm writing a program to count the execution time of a function using clock and I used iomanip to change the output to decimal with 9 zeros.

This is the code that I am using:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void linearFunction(int input)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < input; i++)
    {

    }
}

void execution_time(int input)
{
    clock_t start_time, end_time;

    start_time = clock();
    linearFunction(input);
    end_time = clock();

    double time_taken = double(end_time - start_time) / double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    cout << "Time taken by function for input = " << input << " is : " << fixed
         << time_taken << setprecision(9);
    cout << " sec " << endl;
}

int main()
{
    execution_time(10000);
    execution_time(100000);
    execution_time(1000000);
    execution_time(10000000);
    execution_time(100000000);
    execution_time(1000000000);

    return 0;
}
```

And the output shows:

```
Time taken by function for input = 10000 is : 0.000000 sec
Time taken by function for input = 100000 is : 0.001000000 sec
Time taken by function for input = 1000000 is : 0.002000000 sec
Time taken by function for input = 10000000 is : 0.038000000 sec
Time taken by function for input = 100000000 is : 0.316000000 sec
Time taken by function for input = 1000000000 is : 3.288000000 sec
```

As you can see, the first time I call the function, it doesn't follow the setprecision(9) that I wrote. Why is this and how can I solve this? Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Your code is doing: #1 print the time_taken.  #2 set the precision to 9.  It's no different than:  #1 put shoes on.  #2 put socks on.  And then wondering why the socks are on the outside of the shoe.

Comment: Voting to close as typo.  The precision is set _after_ printing the numbers on the first line.

Comment: I suspect that the point you're missing is that a stream has a state, and manipulating this state (for instance with `setprecision`) has no effect on the output before that point. That is, `cout << ... << setprecision(9);` does not mean "output `...` with precision 9", but "output `...`, then set the precision to 9 for the future".

Comment: A simpler example of what you're observing is `cout << 0.1 << setprecision(100) << 0.1;`, which will print an approximation of 0.1 in two different ways.

Comment: I see, thanks for the answers, everyone. I wasn't too sure on how to use setprecision before, but now I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the following line properly:

```
cout << "Time taken by function for input = " << input << " is : " << fixed << time_taken << setprecision(9);
```

See? You are setting the precision after printing out `time_taken`. So for the first time, you don't see the result of `setprecision()`. But for the second time and onwards, as `setprecision()` has already been executed, you get the desired decimal places.

So to fix this issue, move `setprecision()` before `time_taken` as such:

```
cout << "Time taken by function for input = " << input << " is : " << fixed << setprecision(9) << time_taken;
```

..or you can also do something like this:

```
cout.precision(9);
cout << "Time taken by function for input = " << input << " is : " << fixed << time_taken;
```

Also, consider not using the following line in your code:

```
using namespace std;
```

..as it's considered as a bad practice. Instead use std:: every time like this:

```
std::cout.precision(9);
std::cout << "Time taken by function for input = " << input << " is : " << std::fixed << time_taken;
```

For more information on this, look up to [why is "using namespace std" considered as a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).